# Merging two sorted lists of lists and if there are duplicate values in the inner lists, keep only those from the first one

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates

I have two lists of lists, sorted with respect to the first item of each inner list (represents timestamp) , containing data like this [[time0, voltage0],[time1,voltage1],....]

```py
l1 =[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
l2 =[[0,0],[0.5,0.5],[1,1.2],[1.5,1.5],[2,2]]
```

the goal is to produce a single list of lists containing the elements from both lists and sorted with respect to the first item of the inner lists BUT
if there is an item which his timestamp is the same in both lists, the final list will contain the item **from the other list**.

for the example above the output should be:

```
result = [[0,0],[0,5,0.5],[1,1],[1.5,1.5],[2,2],[3,3]]
```

I've tried to save a reference in each element which will specify from which list the element came and then go over the list to find duplicates and delete those who came from the second list but finding duplicates isn't working since `["first",0,0]` isn't a duplicate of `["second",0,0]`

```py
# examples of lists
import itemgetter

lFirst = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0]]
lSecond = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.2], [1.5, 1.5], [2.0, 2.0], [2.5, 2.5], [3.0, 3.0], [3.5, 3.5], [4.0, 4.0], [4.5, 4.5]]


print "first list: {}".format(lFirst)
print "second list: {}".format(lSecond)

res = sorted(lFirst+lSecond , key = itemgetter(0))
print res
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to concatenate your lists, with `l2` coming first. Then create a dictionary and sort the `items()`:

```
print([list(x) for x in sorted(dict(l2 + l1).items())])
#[[0, 0], [0.5, 0.5], [1, 1], [1.5, 1.5], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

This works because dictionary keys are unique. You start with a key-value pair from `l2`, but if the key (timestamp) also exists in `l1` it gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `heapq.merge` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)) to merge the lists and `itertools.grouby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) to group the elements.

The list which is first in `merge()` will get priority:

```
l1 = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0]]
l2 = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.2], [1.5, 1.5], [2.0, 2.0], [2.5, 2.5], [3.0, 3.0], [3.5, 3.5], [4.0, 4.0], [4.5, 4.5]]

from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby

out = [next(g) for _, g in groupby(merge(l1, l2, key=lambda k: k[0]), lambda k: k[0])]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0.0, 0.0],
 [0.5, 0.5],
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [1.5, 1.5],
 [2.0, 2.0],
 [2.5, 2.5],
 [3.0, 3.0],
 [3.5, 3.5],
 [4.0, 4.0],
 [4.5, 4.5],
 [5.0, 5.0]]
```

EDIT: Works in Python3.5+ (In Python2.7 `merge()` doesn't have `key=` argument)

Comment: doesn't seem to work in python 2.7 since merge doesn't take key as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all duplicates from the second list before merging.

```
lFirst = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0]]
lSecond = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.2], [1.5, 1.5], [2.0, 2.0], [2.5, 2.5], [3.0, 3.0], [3.5, 3.5], [4.0, 4.0], [4.5, 4.5]]

print("first list: {0}".format(lFirst))
print("second list: {0}".format(lSecond))

lFirstTimes = [x[0] for x in lFirst]
lSecondFiltered = [x for x in lSecond if x[0] not in lFirstTimes]
print("second list without duplicates: {0}".format(lSecondFiltered))

res = lFirst+lSecondFiltered
res.sort()
print(res)
```